# unknown diskIO operation

Tags: python, c, linux, disk

I have some big computation programs running, which does not involve disk operation, however, when I monitor the process in `htop`, it shows a lot of disk wait, and CPU utilization is only 10%, I looked up using iotop, I am not seeing any irregular disk read/write, what might be the possible reason for this and how do I debug it? The program is python3 and C, and I am running on Ubuntu 14.04 and Ubuntu 16.04.

Sorry that the program is too big and I don't know which part is malfunctioning, so I can't paste them here for testing.

Comment: Is it possible that it takes so much memory that it uses a lot of SWAP?

Comment: This sounds a bit like a paging issue; yet, iotop should show swap-io... check the output of "free" to see, if swap is used while the program is running

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, but, no, the machine has 512GB memory (yes, I mean RAM, not disk), it only uses around 120GB. @AntonH

Comment: @1a1a11a Then I think more information is needed to track down this issue. Maybe `perf(1)` can shed some light on this.

Comment: Thank you, I agree on this, but I have no idea where to look now, I hope you can give some suggestions to help me find out what is going on under there. What do you mean by `perf(1)`? I tried `man 1 perf`, there is no entry. @Ctx

Comment: perf is a utility that needs to be installed. This explains it, http://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/install-perf-tool-centos-ubuntu/